# Getting errors in axios post method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I simply can't manage to understand what is wrong with this code.
I'm trying to make a post request to logout from an API using axios.
I keep getting error 401 which I believe that it is because the request isn't using the right code, but I already tried it with Authorization, bearer, token, etc. and nothing works.

```
const handleExit = () => {
    const tokenAtual = sessionStorage.getItem("token");
    
    console.log(tokenAtual)

    axios.post("https://api.secureme.pt/api/v1/auth/logout", {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `token ${tokenAtual}`
          }
    }).then(response =>{
        setLoading(false);
        console.log("response.data.message>>>>>>>>>>>" , response.data.message);
        navigate('/')
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("error -> ", error);
        setLoading(false);
        if(error.response.status === 406){
            setError(error.response.data.message);
        }
        else {
            setError("Something went wrong, please try again later.");
        }
        console.log("error -> ", error);
    });
    

}
```

------------Postman code-----------

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.secureme.pt/api/v1/auth/logout' \
--header 'Authorization: ----tokenAtual----'
```

Comment: " I already tryed it with Authorization, bearer, token, etc and nothing works." — What does the documentation for the API say you should use?

Comment: only the token, but that dont work neither

Comment: II already tried it, keeps giving error 401. If it was to no longer have access it should return 406

Comment: It worked there...

Comment: It was post, authentication and the token in the headers tab.
So my code should be like this, right?

axios.post("https://api.secureme.pt/api/v1/auth/logout", {
   headers: {'Authentication': tokenAtual}
  })

Comment: Can you take a look at it, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [axios.post](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config) method :-

```js
axios.post(url[, data[, config]])
```

The first parameter is `url`. Second parameter is `data` and the third parameter is `config`. You are passing `config` in place of `data`.

Here is the fixed form:

```js
axios.post('https://api.secureme.pt/api/v1/auth/logout', undefined, {headers: {
  'Authorization': tokenAtual
}})
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your request is with syntax/params you are sending to post req it should like

```
axios.post(
"https://api.secureme.pt/api/v1/auth/logout",
{},
{
headers:{
'Authorization': `token ${tokenAtual}`
}
})
```

The syntax/param for the post request is

```
(url: string, data?: any, config?: AxiosRequestConfig | undefined)
```

So you are trying to send config in place of data